# Manage self compiled Nginx via systemd

Tags: nginx, systemd

I compiled Nginx from source code and now I want to manage it via systemd like `systemctl start,stop,restart,reload,enable nginx.service`. What I need to do to enable this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to add [NGINX systemd service file](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/systemd/) in `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`.

For your own instance of Nginx (vs. the one provided by your distribution) `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service` could be correct location. It also overrides `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`, when enabled with `systemctl enable nginx.service` (or `reenable`).

```
[Unit]
Description=The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You may need to change the paths depending on where the Nginx you have compiled is located. Here, I assume it's in `/usr/local/sbin/nginx`.

Comment: For hardening the service file, there is very useful info here: https://www.sherbers.de/running-nginx-without-root/